# Undefined value of dynamically filled button

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am generating ion cards with a response. Each ion-car has 3 button. I am sure that I can recieve the response properly. However I cannot give value to the buttons or I am doing it in wrong way.

//here is my html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color='primary'>
    <ion-title>events</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<div class="row" *ngIf="events && events.length > 0">
    <ion-card *ngFor="let event of events">

    <img src="../../img/campus_background.jpg"/>

    <ion-card-content>
      <h1 class="card-title">
        {{event.name}}
      </h1><br>
      <p>Location: {{event.location}}</p><br>
      <p> Start: {{event.start_hour}}</p><br>
      <p> End: {{event.end_hour}}</p><br>
      <p>Organizator: {{event.creator}}</p><br>
      <p> Description: {{event.info}}</p><br>
    </ion-card-content>  
        <ion-row no-padding>
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button clear small [value]="event.id" (click)="addParticipant()" color="danger" icon-left>
          <ion-icon name='person-add'></ion-icon>
          Join
        </button>
      </ion-col >
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button ion-button clear small [value]="event.id" (click)="pushParticipants($event.target.id)" color="danger" icon-left>
          <ion-icon name='people'></ion-icon>
          {{event.id}}
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <button ion-button clear small [value]="event.id" color="danger" icon-left>
          <ion-icon name='share-alt'></ion-icon>
          Share
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-card>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

When I clicked the button that I am calling the pushParticipants() function. I am trying the alert that button value but it says me "undefined"

```
 pushParticipants(id){
    alert(id);
  }
```

I think, there is problem with binding button value but I could not figure it out. I am sure that events array is filling properly with response since the other parts of ion-card filling itself right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using value of button, you can pass directly to the method whole object, like:

```
<button ion-button clear small (click)="addParticipant(event)" color="danger" icon-left>
...
</button>
```

And in your pushParticipants method expect the whole event object

```
pushParticipants(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: I will definitely accept that answer just give me 7 more minutes :)

Comment: that's strange, are you sure event.id really exists? What about event.name, can you access this property in pushParticipants() ?

Comment: Good. glad it helped